# Concurrent actions in admin

Tags: control-panel, admin

I have a plugin the imports data from an external database. This is more of a onetime action. But what I've noticed is that when this process runs, I cannot do anything in the admin section anymore. (and its not CPU or apache blocking) All my other requests (on other tabs) are blocked until the long running process is done. Is this normal behaviour? If so,can that be changed with config settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like delegating the import to a Task would be the best way to implement this. More info in this answer:

[Does Craft have a server-side queuing system?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/does-craft-have-a-server-side-queuing-system/2020#2020)

Answer (score 0):

Well, *something* is blocking it... CPU, Apache, MySQL, PHP, disk I/O, etc.  You can debug that or have your plugin perform it's actions in small batches or over multiple AJAX requests.

Not much that Craft can do to help what you're seeing, though.